# Question applying Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Suppose $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $|f'(x)|\leq 1 $ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, show that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| ≤ |x-y|$$

for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Hello I have this question from my differential analysis class and I'm very stuck on how to answer it.

**Attempt:**

I have a feeling that it has to do with the mean value theorem although I'm not sure how to use the information given about the derivative of $f$ to answer the question at all.

I've only got so far as to write down $-1≤f'(x)≤1$ and $f'(c) = 1$ and have no idea at all how I'm going to tie it to the inequality involving $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Did you try using the Mean Value Theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You can write: $$f(x)-f(y) = f'(c)(x-y) \implies |f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)||x-y|,$$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$. And $|f'(c)| \leq 1,$ so...

Answer (score 2):

You're on the good way: by the mean value theorem and for $x<y$ there's $c\in(x,y)$ such that

$$f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)\implies |f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y|\le |x-y|$$

Answer (score 0):

Try proving the contrapositive: Suppose there exist $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert > \lvert x - y\rvert$ and show that there exists $c$ such that $\lvert f'(c) \rvert > 1$.